# R function for dependent samples t test?

Tags: r, statistics

How to write R function for dependent samples t test? Without using existing function (Such as t.test() )?

```
ttest <- function(x,y) {
 n1<- length(y)       #y length
 n2<- length(x)       #x length
 somay <- sum(y)
 somax <- sum(x)
 y1 <- (somay)/n1       #y mean
 y2<- (somax)/n2        #x mean
 dadosy <- na.omit(y)
 dadosx <- na.omit(x)
 disvquad1 <- (dadosy-y1)^2
 disvquad2 <- (dadosx-y2)^2
 s12<- (1/(n1-1))*sum(disvquad1)    #variance of y
 s22<- (1/(n2-1))*sum(disvquad2)    #variance of x
 s2 <- ((n1-1)*s12+(n2-1)*s22)/((n1-1)+(n2-1))
 s<- (s2)^(1/2)
 t<- (y1-y2)/(sqrt(1/n1+1/n2)*s)     #test statistic 
 return(t)
}

ttest(x,y)
```

Is this the correct solution for dependent samples t-test.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Are you asking if you are using the correct formulas? If so, that's really a question about statistics and belongs on [stats.se]. Seems odd to avoid standard R functions when using R. You should include the formula you are trying to implement if this is really a coding question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [this tutorial](http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf), the paired t-test is nothing but testing difference (or deviance) of two vectors.

Below is a quick trial. It begins to select complete cases between the two vectors (`complete.cases()`). Then mean, standard deviation and standard errors are obtained. Finally the t-static and p-values are calculated - note that the mean difference is 0 by default (`mu = 0`) and the alternative hypothesis is assumed to be two sided.

```
ttest <- function(x, y, mu = 0, ...) {
    # keep only non-NULL
    complete <- complete.cases(x, y)
    x <- x[complete]
    y <- y[complete]
    # build statistic
    d <- y - x
    d.mu <- mean(d)
    d.se <- sd(d) / sqrt(length(x)) # standard error
    t <- (d.mu - mu) / d.se
    # returns t statistic and p value, assumes two sided
    c(t_value = t, p_value = pt(t, df = length(x)-1))
}

set.seed(1237)
ttest(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
#   t_value   p_value 
# 0.9163995 0.8083221
```